# How do I view an external CSS file in Devtools?

Tags: html, css, devtools

If a page's styling is linked in the  section, rather than the styling added directly to the section, how do I view the css file in a browser's devtools?

Comment: To see the file, look in **Sources**

Answer (score 0):

Select the element in the "Elements" tab, then click the link to the CSS file in the "Styles" tab below.

[image: This is where the link will be]